# Add category custom attribute with dropdown

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to add to category a custom atribute , a select with 2 values:

- 0 - "No"
- 1 - "Yes"

I created a module and used this code in installation file:

```
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'top_brand', array(
    'group'                => 'General',
    'type'              => 'int',//can be int, varchar, decimal, text, datetime
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend_input'    => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Top Hersteller',
    'input'             => 'select', //text, textarea, select, file, image, multilselect
    'option' => array(
        'value' => array(

            'optionone'=> array(
                0 =>'No'),
            'optiontwo'=> array(
                0 =>'Yes')
        ),

    ),
    'default' => array(0),
    'class'             => '',
    // 'source'            => '',//this is necessary for select and multilelect, for the rest leave it blank
    'global'             => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,//scope can be SCOPE_STORE or SCOPE_GLOBAL or SCOPE_WEBSITE
    'visible'           => true,
    'frontend_class'     => '',
    'required'          => false,//or true
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'position'            => 100,//any number will do
));
$this->endSetup();
```

Attribute appear in administration panel but value added in select for "No" is 3 and for "Yes" is 4.
How to make value 0 and 1 ?

Comment: @ user4157 : Where I can I add this regard,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'top_brand', array(
    'group'                => 'General',
    'type'              => 'int',//can be int, varchar, decimal, text, datetime
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend_input'    => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Top Hersteller',
    'input'             => 'select', //text, textarea, select, file, image, multilselect
    'default' => array(0),
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',//this is necessary for select and multilelect, for the rest leave it blank
    'global'             => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,//scope can be SCOPE_STORE or SCOPE_GLOBAL or SCOPE_WEBSITE
    'visible'           => true,
    'frontend_class'     => '',
    'required'          => false,//or true
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'position'            => 100,//any number will do
));
$this->endSetup();
```

I added `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean` as `source` for your attribute.

Comment: @Maurius thanks for the answer. But how would the source model `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean` will work for multiselect option ?

Comment: @Vikram If you use that source model for a multiselect you will see a multiselect with 2 options. `Yes/No`.

Comment: @Marius i wan to Yes or No attribute where i have to add file or create new module for this

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below code to create top_brand attribute in category:

```
   $this->addAttribute( 'catalog_category', 'top_brand', array(
                'group' => 'General',
                'type' => 'tinyint',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Top Hersteller',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
                'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '', 
                'unique' => false, 
            ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding the custom yes/no attribute in the category section please create the module and enter the following code.

```
 <?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'featured_product', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Featured Product',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
));

$this->endSetup();`
```

Please refer my tutorial as well.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-add-custom-attribute-dropdown-to-category-section-magento/ (yes/no) attribute

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-add-custom-dropdown-attribute-to-magento-category-section/ (custom options)